# Accessing irreducible representations in GAP character table

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters, gap

I'm writing an algorithm in GAP to automate some easy calculations related to elements of prime order in groups that appear in the ATLAS. 
To automate the process, I need to access the character values for some irreducible complex representations of small degree so I can do some basic arithmetic on them.

Is there any way to access these without computing all of the irreducible characters using the function Irr(G)? Calling Irr(G) takes a very long time to run on my computer (on PSL(4,3), for example) and I really only need the two or three smallest irreducible representations.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the character table is in the ATLAS (or related) you can access it immediately by its name:

```
c:=CharacterTable("L4(3)");;
```

The long time you observe is presumably a call such as

```
gap> d:=CharacterTable(PSL(4,3));;
gap> Irr(d);
```

which stems from calculating the character table afresh from first principles. In this second case you might be able to start with some ad-hoc computations and hope that this gives certain low-degree characters, but there is no generic process that would get all low-degree characters quicker.

In short, unless you need the connection to the group, access the character tables by name, not from constructing a group first.